# Issue converting request param to local date in correct date time format with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I looked up and followed the official spring docs for global Time configuration.

document link : [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat)

And after following the code, I tested it, but it didn't work.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {

    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    registrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    return conversionService;
  }
}
```

```java
  @GetMapping("/date")
  public void test(@RequestParam LocalDate start) {

      System.out.println("start = " + start);
  }
```

request URL = http://localhost:8080/date?start=01.03.2021

error log = Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate

Comment: Have you tried with `http://localhost:8080/date?start=1/3/21`? If it works then the global dateformatter is not configured properly.

Comment: what is 'm/d/yy'? i have set the format "dd.MM.yyyy".
and i try start=1/3/21 but not woking.

Comment: You should be solving this [with the article here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters).

Comment: i knew that article. but it is very dangerous to `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport` it is not recommend. so i'm not using.

Comment: I hope there is a helpful answer